# Commanbutton ERROR

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to load a file, but only the last commanButton it works, if it works perfectly in change the first does not work well.

The first commanbutton of the list does not work, the last one if, here the code:

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm-main">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
                    <p:dataTable var="task" value="#{tareaBean.tareas}">

                        <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                            <h:outputText value="#{task.nombre}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Descripcion">
                            <h:outputText value="#{task.cuerpo}"/>
                        </p:column>

                         <p:column headerText="Fecha Inicio">
                             <h:outputText value="#{task.fechaInicio}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Fecha Final">
                            <h:outputText value="#{task.fechaFinal}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Subir archivo">
                            <p:panel>
                            <p:fileUpload  value="#{tareaBean.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" update = "messages" rendered="true" />

                            </p:panel>
                            <h:commandButton   value="Subir"  actionListener="#{tareaBean.cargar()}"/>

               <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/> 
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>
                       </h:form>
```

the function here :

```
public void cargar(){
       String extValidate;
       if(getFile()!=null){
           String ext = getFile().getFileName();
           if(ext!=null){
               extValidate = ext.substring(ext.indexOf(".")+1);
           }
           else{extValidate = "null";}
           if(extValidate.equals("pdf")){
               try{
                   TransferFile(getFile().getFileName(),getFile().getInputstream());
               }catch(IOException ex){
                   Logger.getLogger(FileUploadControl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
                   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                   context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage("Error","Error subiendo el archivo"));
               }
               FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
               context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("EXITO",getFile().getFileName()+" cargado exitosamente, tipo de contenido: "+getFile().getContentType()+" tamaño :"+getFile().getSize()));
           }
           else{
               FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
               context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage("Error_ext","Solo se pemite archivos con extension .pdf"));
           }
       }
       else{
           FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage("Error","Seleccione una fila"));
           }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: Sorry for the capital letters..

Comment: You want to [improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44144046/edit).